# r for loop only returns last value or NULL

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

```
for(i in 1:ncol(cov_portfolio)){
    k<-cov_portfolio[i,i]}
k
```

my cov_portfolio is 12:12 matrix and whenever i run this code to see each matching column and row, like [1,1] and [10,10], it shows only the last value.
is there any other way i can do it?

Thanks

Comment: First, this loop/code won't work (you have typo in it); Second, to skip looping you can use function `diag()`; Third, if your question is - how to return result from for loop then it's duplicate of many [questions that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154748/store-values-in-for-loop) [there are on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689387/loop-in-r-how-to-save-the-outputs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store values in For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154748/store-values-in-for-loop)

Comment: `k=numeric(12);for(i in 1:ncol(cov_portfolio))   k[i]<-cov_portfolio[i,i];k`

Answer (score 2):

very, very similar to Michael's answer:

```
    k <- numeric(12) # create a vector of length 12

    for(i in 1:ncol(cov_portfolio))
    {
        k <- c(k, cov_portfolio[i, i]) # add onto k vector
    }

    k # view vector to compare results
```

Michael is right - you were reassigning the value k over and over again, so of course you would only see one value.

Answer (score 0):

Right now each loop your code rewrites K each loop. If you want to see every answer you can do the following:

```
  k <- c()
    for(i in 1:ncol(cov_portfolio)){
        k <- c(k,cov_portfolio[i,i])}
   k
```

Comment: If you're going to suggest this approach (rather than just using `diag()`), at least pre-allocate `k` to a suitable length.